# C# Receive definite number of bytes in Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an FPGA sending my C# programm always 4 bytes at the piece. My c# program receives the 4 bytes but waits until serialPort timeout event occurs, but FPGA wants to send the next 4 bytes. To speed up this process I would like to know how I can configure the serialPort (the msdn serialPort class) function readByte to receive only 4 bytes without waiting for timeout.

Or should I rather use readLine and send an line end after sending 4 bytes? What is the specific Ascii code for line end? I found 0D 0A. Does it matter which one OD or 0A I use to signal line end?

Comment: doesn't SerialPort.Read() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=netframework-4.7.1 and specifying the 4 as count work?

Comment: you say bytes but it would need to be ASCII if you want to use ReadLine()

Comment: I want to read out a simple ram on FPGA which has 32 Bit width data per slot and 128 slots. I want to transfer 32 bit (4 bytes) as one paket behind each other for all 128 slots. When I transfer 4 bytes and then the next 4 bytes without break the c# program will read 8 bytes and convert them wrongly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want 4 bytes at a time use SerialPort.Read() like this.

```cs
byte[] data = new byte[4]; // buffer to contain results of the read.
SerialPort.Read(data, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx), the `ReadByte` function reads a single byte. If a `TimeoutExcepion` is thrown, you must be calling the function for than four times, or the FPGA isn't sending four bytes.

To read four bytes, you should use something like:

```
 int[] data = new int[4];
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     data[i] = port.ReadByte();
 }
```